# nginx redirection problem correct configuration but 404 return

Tags: web-services, nginx, server, devops, nginx-config

so i start using Nginx for my first project, but i have problem with redirection my config file it looks good but whenever i tried to "curl IP_address/redirect_me" an 404 shows up any help
i did check error.log and nginx -t but no solution yet, and "curl IP_address work" perfect.
(not that i'm still learning web development)

this is my default config file

```
ubuntu@381927-web-01:~$ sudo cat  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    location / {
        return 301 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4;
    }
    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
ubuntu@381927-web-01:~$
```

this the error:

```
ubuntu@381927-web-01:~$ curl http://35.153.18.176/redirect_me
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
ubuntu@3819
```